# A minimal criminal application to sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

**A sequence a1, a2, a3, … of positive integers has the property that a1 = 1 and, for each k ≥ 1, ak < ak+1 ≤ 2ak. For any sequence with this property prove that every positive integer n can be expressed as a sum of distinct terms of the sequence (ak), i.e. when n is expressed in this way, no particular term ak occurs more than once.**

The solution for this question starts out simple enough:

Let P(n) be the statement "n can be expressed as a sum of distinct ak"

P(1) is true since 1 = a1. Let's assume it's not the case that P(n) is true for all integers n ≥ 1. Take the least positive n such that P(n) is false. n > 1 as P(1) holds and as n is the minimal criminal we have P(m) for 1 ≤ m < n.

Therefore, m is an integer with 1 ≤ m < n and can be expressed as a sum of terms from the sequence (ak), with no term used more than once. Let as be the largest member of (ak) not greater than n. Then n < a(s+1) ≤ 2as.

The written solution to this question then states:

**"From which it follows that m = n - as < as"**

My question is: Why? How does it follow? I understand that as n < 2as, now obviously n - as < as. But why need this be equal to m. Surely m could be greater than as but less than n? Or as may be equal to m? Am I missing something.

Comment: Why the adjective "criminal" in your title ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That statement is actually **defining** $m$ to be $n-a_s$: that’s the particular positive integer less than $n$ that we want to consider. I expect that the argument goes on to say that $P(m)$ holds, since $1\le m<n$, so $m$ is the sum of distinct terms $a_k$, say

$$m=a_{k_1}+\ldots+a_{k_\ell}\,,$$

where $k_1<k_2<\ldots<k_\ell$. And $m<a_s$, so $a_{k_\ell}<a_s$, so

$$n=m+a_s=a_{k_1}+\ldots+a_{k_\ell}+a_s$$

expresses $n$ as a sum of distinct members of the sequence. Thus, $n$ isn’t a ‘criminal’ after all, and this contradiction shows that there are no ‘criminals’ and hence that $P(n)$ is true for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Okay but isn't m meant to be any positive integer less than n? I don't understand the particular logic here. Are you defining m to be something new, and so in this case could you use a different letter for the new definition? Because what's stopping m (by the old definition) from being greater than as but less than n? I understand the logic if you let it equal say p, but are they just using the same letter for a different definition?

Comment: @SamConnell: The first use of $m$ was as a dummy variable, a temporary name for any positive integer less than $n$. That use does not give $m$ any particular value and is strictly local to that statement; $m$ is free to be used later for other purposes. In the statement about which you asked, $m$ is actually being assigned a specific value, $n-a_s$; after that $m$ is no longer free to be used for something else, because it’s been given a specific meaning. You could change the first $m$ to $i,j$, or $k$, leaving everything else unchanged, and the meaning of the whole thing would be unchanged.